# Angular webpack compiled successfully, stuck in compile stage - webpage didn't opened

Tags: angular, webpack

When execed `npm start`, the first compiling will done successfully.

BUT! When I save the app code, the compiling will stucked.
Just display webpack: Compiling... in shell

[image]

Comment: Can you post the exact message? And can you also run webpack with `--verbose` and see if you get any more details?

Comment: not show any error only display message webpack: Compiled successfully

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's exactly what it's supposed to look like. Now go to your browser and hit the URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

If you want the output to automatically open after compilation in your browser, then pass `--open` argument while hitting `ng serve`:

```
ng serve --open
```

If you want the process to happen automatically whenever you hit `npm start` then you should modify the `scripts` property from `package.json` of your project:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    ...
},
...
```

Now whenever you hit `npm start` it will compile as well as open the webpage for that project.

Answer (score 1):

Angular webpack compiled successfully, stuck in compile stage - webpage didn't opened

this is not a error in this message is successfully running on your angular.

if you stop this angular running you simply open the ng command  press the "ctrl + C" the angular compilation is stopped